# URL Rewriting not working with ZF and apache2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

This has got me baffled.  I recently set up VM in a hurry to go travelling.  I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and LAMP.  The PHP version is 5.5 and Apache is 2.4.  I have used this same configuration on my home machine and it works fine.

Anyhow, the problem is that I can only access actions on the index controller of my ZF application, e.g: domainname/, domainname/index/info.  If I try any other controllers, e.g. domainname/test/view, I get the apache 404 error.  (Note - NOTE the ZF Not Found error).

I imagine this is a problem with URL rewriting, but the .htaccess on my VM is the same as my home machine, and I can't see anything in the virtual host configuration that would cause this.  Also, if it was simply an URL rewriting problem, I would have thought it would come in to play for ALL urls, including the index controller...

Here's my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Ideas?

EDIT: Here's the virtual host config:

DocumentRoot /home/kim/www/vhost/public
    ServerName koop
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

```
<Directory /home/kim/www/vhost/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had to change AllowOverride to All.  That means Apache2 will now process my .htaccess files.

Then I needed to enable mod rewrite, by `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, then restart apache, i.e. `sudo service apache2 restart`